# Inherit Interface Implementation

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I'm new to *C++* but have some programming experience in high-level languages (Java, etc.). The main problem I'm currently facing is to understand inheritance and interfaces in *C++*.

***testsurface.h***

```
#include <QSurface>

class TestSurface : public virtual QSurface
{
public:
    TestSurface(SurfaceClass clazz) : QSurface(clazz) { }
    ~TestSurface() { }

    virtual QSurfaceFormat      format()        = 0;
    virtual QSize               size()          = 0;
    virtual QPlatformSurface*   surfaceHandle() = 0;
    virtual SurfaceType         surfaceType()   = 0;
};
```

***testwindow.h***

```
#include <QWindow>
#include "testsurface.h"

class TestWindow : public QWindow, public TestSurface
{
public:
    TestWindow() : QWindow(), TestSurface(QWindow::Window) { }
    ~TestWindow() { }
};
```

In my understanding, `TestSurface` passes all abstract methods from `QSurface` along. Because of `TestWindow` is inheriting `QWindow` which is inheriting `QSurface` I would expect that all needed methods of `TestSurface::QSurface` are implemented through `TestWindow::QWindow` but this isn't the case because I get following error messages upon building:

```
C2512: C:\...\Qt\Projects\Test2\testwindow.h:10: Erroe: C2512: 'QSurface::QSurface': no appropriate default constructor available
```

and

```
C:\...\Qt\Projects\Test2\main.cpp:12: Error: C2259: 'TestWindow': Instance of abstract class can't be created because of following members:
"QSurfaceFormat TestSurface::format(void)": is abstract
    c:\...\qt\projects\test2\testsurface.h(12): See declaration of 'TestSurface::format'
"QSize TestSurface::size(void)": is abstract
    c:\...\qt\projects\test2\testsurface.h(13): See declaration of 'TestSurface::size'
"QPlatformSurface *TestSurface::surfaceHandle(void)": is abstract
    c:\...\qt\projects\test2\testsurface.h(14): See declaration of 'TestSurface::surfaceHandle'
"QSurface::SurfaceType TestSurface::surfaceType(void)": is abstract
    c:\...\qt\projects\test2\testsurface.h(15): See declaration of 'TestSurface::surfaceType'
"QSurfaceFormat QSurface::format(void) const": is abstract
    D:\...\msvc2013_64_opengl\include\QtGui/qsurface.h(67): See declaration of 'QSurface::format'
"QPlatformSurface *QSurface::surfaceHandle(void) const": is abstract
    D:\...\msvc2013_64_opengl\include\QtGui/qsurface.h(68): See declaration of 'QSurface::surfaceHandle'
"QSurface::SurfaceType QSurface::surfaceType(void) const": is abstract
    D:\...\msvc2013_64_opengl\include\QtGui/qsurface.h(70): See declaration of 'QSurface::surfaceType'
"QSize QSurface::size(void) const": is abstract
     D:\...\msvc2013_64_opengl\include\QtGui/qsurface.h(73): See declaration of 'QSurface::size'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work, `QWindow` is not using virtual inheritance when inheriting `QSurface`.

```
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QWindow : public QObject, public QSurface {...};
```

If you want multiple interfaces to "join a base interface", they all must use virtual inheritance.

```
           Base
            / \
           /   \
  virtual /     \ virtual
     Der1         Der2
          \     /
           \   /
            \ /
           Join
```

Comment: Hmm, okay I see that. But if I want to preserve my setup, I then would have to wrap the `QWindow::QSurface` implementation. Like `QSize TestWindow::size() { return QWindow::size(); }` , but here is the problem, `QWindow::surfaceHandle()` is private in `QWindow`. Seems like I can't do what I wanted to.

Comment: @BastiFunck - you can get a handle to the `QPlatformWindow` via `QWindow::handle()`, `QPlatformWindow` inherits `QPlatformSurface` which has public `QSurface *surface() const` if getting the surface is what you need.

Comment: Now that I know I have to go the way with wrapping the implementation, that would have been the next step to find out how to get the handle of QWindow. Thanks for saving me some time with googling